# Making moves w/ websockets and python / django ( / twisted? )

Tags: python, django, sockets, websocket

The fun part of websockets is sending essentially unsolicited content from the server to the browser right?

Well, I'm using django-websocket by Gregor Müllegger.  It's a really wonderful early crack at making websockets work in Django.

I have accomplished "hello world."  The way this works is:  when a request is a websocket, an object, websocket, is appended to the request object.  Thus, I can, in the view interpreting the websocket, do something like:

```
request.websocket.send('We are the knights who say ni!')
```

That works fine.  I get the message back in the browser like a charm.

But what if I want to do that without issuing a request from the browser at all?

OK, so first I save the websocket in the session dictionary:

```
request.session['websocket'] = request.websocket
```

Then, in a shell, I go and grab the session by session key.  Sure enough, there's a websocket object in the session dictionary.  Happy!

However, when I try to do:

```
>>> session.get_decoded()['websocket'].send('With a herring!')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Sad.  :-(

OK, so I don't know much of anything about sockets, but I know enough to sniff around in a debugger, and lo and behold, I see that the socket in my debugger (which is tied to the genuine websocket from the request) has fd=6, while the one that I grabbed from the session-saved websocket has fd=-1.

Can a socket-oriented person help me sort this stuff out?

Comment: @EliCourtwright You haven't awarded the bounty..

Comment: @paddila: Yeah, it makes you wait 24 hours even if the reason you give for opening the bounty is "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."  I'll award the bounty as soon as the system will let me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm the author of django-websocket. I'm not a real expert in the topic of websockets and networking, however I think I have a decent understanding of whats going on. Sorry for going into great detail. Even if most of the answer isn't specific to your question it might help you at some other point. :-)

---

## How websockets work

Let me explain shortly what a websocket is. A websocket starts as something that really looks like a plain HTTP request, established from the browser. It indicates through a HTTP header that it wants to "upgrade" the protocol to be a websocket instead of a HTTP request. If the server supports websockets, it agrees on the handshake and both - server and client - now know that they will use the established tcp socket formerly used for the HTTP request as a connection to interchange websocket messages.

Beside sending and waiting for messages, they have also of course the ability to close the connection at any time.

## How django-websocket abuses the python's wsgi request environment to hijack the socket

Now lets get into the details of how django-websocket implements the "upgrading" of the HTTP request in a django request-response cylce.

Django usually uses the WSGI specification to talk to the webserver like apache or gunicorn etc. This specification was designed just with the very limited communication model of HTTP in mind. It assumes that it gets a HTTP request (only incoming data) and returns the response (only outgoing data). This makes it tricky to force django into the concept of a websocket where bidirectional communication is allowed.

What I'm doing in django-websocket to achieve this is that I dig very deeply into the internals of WSGI and django's request object to retrieve the underlaying socket. This tcp socket is then used to handle the upgrade the HTTP request to a websocket instance directly.

**Now to your original question ...**

I hope the above makes it obvious that when a websocket is established, there is no point in returning a HttpResponse. This is why you usually don't return anything in a view that is handled by django-websocket.

However I wanted to stick close to the concept of a view that holds the logic and returns data based on the input. This is why you should only use the code in your view to handle the websocket.

After you return from the view, the websocket is automatically closed. This is done for a reason: We don't want to keep the socket open for an undefined amount of time and relying on the client (the browser) to close it.

This is why you cannot access a websocket with django-websocket outside of your view. The file descriptor is then of course set to -1 indicating that its already closed.

## Disclaimer

I explained above that I'm digging in the surrounding environment of django to get somehow -- in a very hackish way -- access to the underlaying socket. This is very fragile and also not supposed to work since WSGI is not designed for this! I also explained above that the websocket is closed after the view ends - however after the websocket closed down (AND closed the tcp socket), django's WSGI implementation tries to send a HTTP response - it doesn't know about websockets and thinks it is in a normal HTTP request-response cycle. But the socket is already closed an the sending will fail. This usually causes an exception in django.

This didn't affected my testings with the development server. The browser will never notice (you know .. the socket is already closed ;-) - but raising an unhandled error in every request is not a very good concept and may leak memory, doesn't handle database connection shutdown correctly and many athor things that *will* break at some point if you use django-websocket for more than experimenting.

This is why I would really advise you ***not to use websockets with django*** yet. It doesn't work by design. Django and especially WSGI would need a total overhaul to solve these problems (see [this discussion for websockets and WSGI](http://groups.google.com/group/paste-users/browse_thread/thread/2f3a5ba33b857c6c)). Since then I would suggest using something like [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/). Eventlet has a working websocket implementation (I borrowed some code from eventlet for the initial version of django-websocket) and since its just plain python code you can import your models and everything else from django. The only drawback is that you need a second webserver running just to handle websockets.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer.  I'm waiting to accept it until I can give you a bounty for it.  :-)

Comment: does this mean that to serve the websocket, one should simply hold open the request? How would you send unsolicited messages if the messages iterator blocks while waiting for incoming messages?

Comment: @Thomas yes you should hold the request open (since its the socket for the websocket - makes sense?). You don't need to block while waiting for messages, you can check periodically for new things with the `read()` and `has_messages()` methods. Read the README here: https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-websocket You can then ofcourse trigger the sending of a message at any time.

Comment: I think is important: **Eventlet has a working websocket implementation and since its just plain python code you can import your models and everything else from django**: You can use django like a library, but not the request,response,middleware,... parts.

Answer (score 6):

As Gregor Müllegger pointed out, Websockets can't be properly handled by WSGI, because that protocol never was designed to handle such a feature.
[uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), since version 1.9.11, can handle Websockets out of the box. Here uWSGI communicates with the application server using raw HTTP rather than the WSGI protocol. A server written that way, can therefore handle the protocol internals and keep the connection open over a long period. Having long living connections handled by a Django view is not a good idea either, because they then would block a worker thread, which is a limited resource.

The main purpose of Websockets, is to have the server push messages to the client in an asynchronous way. This can be a Django view triggered by other browsers (ex.: chat clients, multiplayer games), or an event triggered by, say django-celery (ex.: sport results). It therefore is fundamental for these Django services, to use a message queue for pushing messages to the client.

To handle this in a scalable way, I wrote [django-websocket-redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), a Django module which can keep open all those long living Websocket connections in one single thread/process using Redis as the backend message queue.

Comment: Thank you for adding insight to this aging question!

Comment: +1 for `django-websocket-redis`, very simple to install/use once you are familiar to the suggested `nginx` & `uWSGI` combo

Answer (score 2):

You could give stargate a bash:  http://boothead.github.com/stargate/ and http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stargate/.

It's built on top of pyramid and eventlet (I also contributed a fair bit of the websocket support and tests to eventlet). The big advantage of pyramid for this sort of thing is that it's got the concept of a resource which the url maps to, rather than just the result of a callable. So you end up with a graph of persistent resources that maps to your url structure and websocket connections are simply routed and connected to those resources.

So you end up only needing to do two things:

```
class YourView(WebSocketView):

    def handler(self, websocket):
        self.request.context.add_listener(websocket)
        while True:
            msg = websocket.wait()
            # Do something with message
```

To receive messages
and

```
resource.send(some_other_message)
```

Here resource is an instance of a stargate.resource.WebSocketAwareContext (as is self.request.context) above and the send method sends the message to all clients connected with the add_listener method.

To publish a message to all of the connected clients you just call `node.send(message)`

I'm hopefully going to write up a little example app in the next week or two to demonstrate this a little better.

Feel free to ping me on github if you want some help with it.

Comment: Ben - this looks like cause for optimism.  You have my attention! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`request.websocket` is probably get closed when you return from the request handler (view). The simple solution is to keep the handler alive (by not returning from the view). If your server is not multi-threaded you won't be able to accept any other simultaneous requests.

Comment: But what's the point of that then?  If I need to keep the request alive in the view, I'm right back at Comet.  The whole point of websockets is to be able to push content to the browser without having to keep the request alive, is it not?

Comment: @Justin Myles Holmes: read disclaimer on http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-websocket

Comment: Yep, I saw that.  That's no problem, for two reasons: 1) I am using the multithreaded runserver that comes with django-websocket, 2) I am fully prepared to use a websocket-ready server solution; either Apache / mod_python with pywebsocket (blegh) or Twisted (yay) - but at the moment I can't even test it out.  I need to understand more about why this socket is not available to me from the shell.