# Twisted and Websockets: Beyond Echo

Tags: python, twisted, comet, websocket, twisted.web

In my ongoing curiosity about websockets, I'm noticing a trend:

The "hello world" of the websocket universe, at least at the moment, seems to be "echo" functionality.  That is, the demonstrated application is typically, "I send something, I receive something."

While aptly demonstrating that the protocol is functional, this example only actually demonstrates the same type of communication that the traditional request / response cycle enables.

For example, the only demonstration (on the server side) that I can find of twisted.web.websockets is the following:

```
import sys
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.web.websocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketSite


class Echohandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def frameReceived(self, frame):
        log.msg("Received frame '%s'" % frame)
        self.transport.write(frame + "\n")


def main():
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
    root = File(".")
    site = WebSocketSite(root)
    site.addHandler("/ws/echo", Echohandler)
    reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I instead examine "push" capability here?  ie, how I can leave the web socket open, and then later, at some time determined by the occurrence of some event, send a message through the websocket, the content of which is also influenced by this event?

(Those interested by this question might also regard as compelling this question that I asked a few days ago: [Making moves w/ websockets and python / django ( / twisted? )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363899/making-moves-w-websockets-and-python-django-twisted))

Comment: Given that websockets are disabled in Firefox 4 http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/12/websockets-disabled-in-firefox-4/ , and even when they're done, they might want not work in all browsers, you probably want to investigate a higher-level abstraction for your two-way browser communication.  Websockets are just a way to optimize things like Athena http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow/Athena and Orbited http://orbited.org/ .

Comment: As shoddy as the current spec (and support) is, aren't websockets actually a complete remake of Comet (Athena, Orbited, etc.?).  For the moment, I'm not interested in solutions that will work in all browsers; I just want to build something that will work between myself and other members of a collective - we'll have full control over our browser and firewall conditions.

Comment: No, not necessarily.  Athena is a complete high-level messaging system, it doesn't just transport bytes.  And Orbited can use multiple transports, falling back to more primitive / less efficient techniques as it determines that the better ones aren't available.  This is something you want even in your situation, because if something *better* than websockets comes along, you'd probably like to take advantage of it without having to rewrite all your code.

Comment: @Glyph: Amazing.  This is point #6 in the question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310706/django-comet-push-least-of-all-evils (outstanding 50 point bounty! ;-)).  Can you show a quick demonstration of how Orbited can be used with Websockets and then fall back to long-polling in the absence of proper support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [hendrix](https://github.com/hendrix/hendrix), I showed how to set up a web app in [a talk at Django-NYC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92VeMkjM1TQ) that uses websockets to push messages from a telnet server to a web page.

Answer (score 9):

This is an example of an updated EchoHandler that will instead of just being reactive, be proactive.

```
class ChattyHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write('oh hai\n')
        self.saysomething()

    def saysomething(self):
        self.transport.write('still there?\n')
        reactor.callLater(5, self.saysomething)
```

*Unfortunately, websockets from https://github.com/rlotun/txWebSocket/ doesn't seem to have the connectionMade() method, and instead the only thing you can hook into is the* __init__. *usually you would just override connectionMade() if it were a 'normal' twisted protocol.* **--Fixed in upstream**

Comment: This raises TypeError: __init__() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebSocketTransport

Comment: I maintain https://github.com/rlotun/txWebSocket/ and I have just added a `connectionMade` hook.