# Enable keep-alive in django for persistent connection

Tags: django, websocket

I keep seeing references for `keep-alive` as a way to help maintain persistent connection, but I can't find any information on how to implement this with Django. How can I access this setting for Django? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in this question: [Keeping connection open in Django without websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146501/keeping-connection-open-in-django-without-websockets) Django doesn't support this `keep-alive` header as it is mostly a request/response framework. However, unlike that question you don't mention not wanting to use websockets, so...

Websockets would be the way to have a persistent connection and there is a really nice library which adds this functionality to Django called [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Using this you can establish a persistent connection to the client and send data to the client without it constantly having to request new information. There's a great tutorial in the documentation and general research on websockets should yield some useful information as well.