# Socket.io for other platform than node.js

Tags: c++, python, sockets, socket.io

I'm looking for a library that work exactly like socket.io(node.js) but I need it in other platform, c++ or maybe python.

This is about server application for website. My app work with node.js but I need to change it for C++/python or something other.

socket.io is great because it choose technology automatically to connect with server - depend which browser/hardware you use.

Any ideas?

Comment: For C++ go with Boost.ASIO, it also allows for asynch handling and it's pretty darn fast http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python, you could look into  >> Websockets with python << 
[Can I use Socket.IO with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190186/can-i-use-socket-io-with-django) 
Django is a web-framework that uses Python language.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Socket.IO implementation for python via [TornadIO2](https://github.com/mrjoes/tornadio2), which is to be used with the [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) async web server. I have used this when it was TornadIO 1.0

[Go](http://golang.org/) has one that I use, but its only compatible to Socket.IO 0.6.x: [go-socket.io](https://github.com/justinfx/go-socket.io)

And just look at the socket.io Wiki for other links:
https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki

Answer (score 1):

The protocol definition for socket.io is available here
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec

I have been part of a couple of project where we decided to actually implement our own client for various reasons. It is not that hard especially since you only have to support on transport (xhr-polling is the easiest imho).

And also maybe a possibility to give back to the community....