# How to create video conference in flutter and django?

Tags: python, django, flutter, video-streaming

I want create a app thats need to have video conference for multiple users(50 maybe), How can I create this in `python django` and `flutter` or react native (for mobile app) ?

I have never used video stream, Please direct me.

Comment: I recommend using sockets, sockets with django: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190186/can-i-use-socket-io-with-django, sockets with javascript: https://socket.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jitsi meet, which is a completely free video conferencing.

Link : https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet